# Working setup for Weblogic 12c, Jersey and Swagger

Tags: jersey, weblogic, swagger, weblogic12c

I have a working Tomcat setup with Jersey and Swagger, but now I have to make it work on Weblogic 12c (12.2.1). I have tried several different ways of getting it to work, but I have ended up in various dead ends. I'm doing this in JDeveloper.

I've ended up with Jackson version issues and other similar collisions every way I've tried. I've gotten Jersey to work with Weblogic, but not Swagger.

I can use older versions if that helps.

This is a part of my pom from my latest failure:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs.javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.1-0-0</version>
    </dependency>
```

This gives

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector.findPropertyIndex(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/Annotated;)Ljava/lang/Integer;
```

which I understand is due to a Glassfish/Jackson version issue.

**tl;dr**
I'm looking for a Hello World for Weblogic 12/Jersey/Swagger

Answer (score 3):

WebLogic Server provides an older version of Jackson that conflicts with the one needed by Swagger.
To tell WebLogic to use the one embedded in your war, add the following to your weblogic.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.7/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    (...)
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>
    </container-descriptor>
    (...)
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a working configuration **for Weblogic 12.1.3**, as follows.

1. I assume that you already have deployed JAX-RS 2.0 as a shared library
2. In the `weblogic-application.xml`, I listed all the "prefer-application-packages" listed in the deploy JAX-RS 2.0:

   ```
   <weblogic-application>
       <library-ref>
           <library-name>jax-rs</library-name>
           <specification-version>2.0</specification-version>
           <exact-match>false</exact-match>
       </library-ref>
       <prefer-application-packages>
           <package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</package-name>
           <package-name>com.google.common.*</package-name>
           <package-name>com.sun.jersey.*</package-name>
           <package-name>org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.*</package-name>
           <package-name>org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.*</package-name>
           <package-name>weblogic.jaxrs.api.client.*</package-name>
           <package-name>weblogic.jaxrs.internal.api.client.*</package-name>
           <package-name>weblogic.jaxrs.dispatch.*</package-name>
           <package-name>weblogic.jaxrs.monitoring.util.*</package-name>
       </prefer-application-packages>
   </weblogic-application>
   ```
3. in the `pom.xml`, I excluded some conflicting dependencies:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
       <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
       <version>${swagger.version}</version>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
               <artifactId>
                   jersey-container-servlet-core
               </artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
               <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a discrepancy in the versions of jackson jars. Newer versions of jackson jars (which are not included in jersey2.x) have com.fasterxml.jackson packages, while old Jersey 1.x have org.codehaus.jackson packages.

Either way, we can always include the latest version of jackson in our dependency.

Comment: Quite some time have passed since I asked this question. I have moved on on a different path, so I don't have that need anymore. For the sake of knowledge sharing and if you have an idea on how to solve it - please share!